# Storing a tuple of integers from user into a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am supposed to take input of two numbers separated by spaces from the user, save it in a tuple and then put that tuple in a list.

What I tried was

```
>>> n=[]
>>> n.append(tuple(raw_input().strip().split(' ')))
1 2
```

the output was

```
>>> n
[('1','2')]
```

I require an output of the form

```
>>> n
[(1,2)]
```

Comment: n.append(tuple(map(int, raw_input().strip().split(' '))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use map

```
>>> n = []
>>> n.append(tuple(map(int, raw_input().strip().split())))
```

You need not call split(' ') explicitly as split splits the string based on space by default

Answer (score 2):

Cast the output into integers:

```
>>> n=[]
>>> n.append(tuple(int(x) for x in raw_input().strip().split(' ')))
1 2
>>> n
[(1, 2)]
```